# Try-catch setup in node.js

Tags: node.js, controller, routes, try-catch

I am trying to setup a **try-catch** for the first time for the following scenario. At the moment I have one inside the **route**, in **server.js** and it does not catch if there is an **error** coming from the **controller**, which is **user.js**.

I am also in doubt if do I need to/can I setup a try-catch also for the controller.

Please help me to setup this properly.

server.js:

```
 app.post('/login-user', (req, res) => {
        try {
            user.loginUser(req.body, (err, jResult) => {
                let token = jwt.sign({
                    user: jResult,
                }, "supersecret")
                console.log(jResult)
                return res.send(token)
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return res.send(jResult)
        }        
    })
```

user.js:

```
user.loginUser = (jUserData, fCallback) => {
    var aData = [
        jUserData.email,
        jUserData.mobile_number,
        1
    ]
    var sQuery = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND mobile_number = ? AND active = ?'
    db.each(sQuery, aData, function (err, jRow) {
        console.log(jRow)
        if (err) {
            console.log('BAD, user not logged in')
            return fCallback(true, {
                status: "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
            })
        }
        if (!Object.keys(jRow).length) {
            console.log('NOT FOUND')
            return fCallback(true, {
                status: "NOT FOUND"
            })
        }
        console.log('GREAT, user logged in')
        return fCallback(false, jRow)
        console.log(jRow)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work quite the way you think.. in your app.post('/login-user', handler, the try.. catch block won't catch errors since the callback is going to be called asynchronously. The best way to deal with errors here is a common pattern in Node.js. Set the err variable to something if you get an error in the loginUser function. e.g.

```
user.loginUser = (jUserData, fCallback) => {
    var aData = [
        jUserData.email,
        jUserData.mobile_number,
        1
    ]
    var sQuery = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND mobile_number = ? AND active = ?'
    db.each(sQuery, aData, function (err, jRow) {
        console.log(jRow)
        if (err) {
            console.log('BAD, user not logged in')
            return fCallback(new Error('BAD, user not logged in: ' + err.message), {
            status: "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
            });
        }
        if (!Object.keys(jRow).length) {
            console.log('NOT FOUND')
            return fCallback(new Error('User not found'), {
            status: "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
            });
        }
        console.log('GREAT, user logged in')
        return fCallback(false, jRow)
        console.log(jRow)
    })
}
```

Then in the app.post handler you check for the err variable being non-null:

```
 app.post('/login-user', (req, res) => {
    user.loginUser(req.body, (err, jResult) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            return res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
        }
        let token = jwt.sign({
            user: jResult,
        }, "supersecret")
        console.log(jResult)
        return res.send(token)
    })    
})
```

Comment: I know this approach but the requirement is to use try..catch since then the server does not crash as it does with other error handlings.

Comment: Hmmm.. the server should not crash if an error is returned in the login user function. Maybe give it a try and see if it crashes? Just be aware that, in general wrapping an asynchronous call in a try/catch block is not going to work!

Comment: If using try/catch is really a hard requirement in itself (though I agree with Terry that it's not an adequate solution here) you can consider using a promisified version of db with async/await syntax. In that case try/catch would work similarly as you'd expect.

Comment: and how would the promisified version of db with async/await syntax look like?

Comment: In that case user.loginUser should return a promise. You'd call inside an async function like:  let result = await user.loginUser(....). . You can then wrap this in a try/catch block and it will work a @Szellem says.

Comment: If it's sqlite3 what you're using then it has a version which uses promises:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite
Even if it's something else, most db access libraries have such versions.

Comment: I see. thank you for the ideas e but I am not familiar with promises and I would like to stick with this way of coding cause this is for an exam and they did not teach us promises but I need to use try-catch somehow. Is there really no way to implement try-catch in this?

Comment: Try.. Catch makes sense only with synchronous code.. most I/O calls in Node are asynchronous, so they will be redundant a lot of the time. It's better to use the err object in callbacks to handle these errors.